# Do assesment or make assesment?

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs

What should I use for this sentence? I **do** compliance assessments in facilities every day. Or I **make** compliance assessments every day. Thank you.

Comment: ["conduct/give/make an assessment The first thing you must do is make an assessment of the situation."](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assessment)

Comment: I ***perform*** assessments...

Comment: I ***conduct*** assessments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not necessary to *do* or *make* anything to investigate compliance; **assess** is already a transitive verb.
From https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/assess:

**Assess**: verb *t.*

> to judge or decide the amount, value, quality, or importance of something:
>
> -The insurers will need to assess the flood damage.
>
> -They assessed the cost of the flood damage at £2,500.
>
> -Exams are not the only means of assessing a student's ability.
>
> -It's too early to assess the long-term consequences of the two countries' union.

Your example could be re-worded: "I assess compliance in facilities every day."

Or, since a compliance assessment is *the process of considering the amount or value of something, or the decision that is made*, you could say, according to https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/assessment:

> **carry out/make an assessment** The lender will send out a valuer or surveyor to make an assessment of the property.

Comment: Why the down-vote?

Comment: Probably because it doesn't answer the question. OP asked about verb-noun collocations, but this answer is about the definition of the verb, which is off-topic

Comment: @gotube Ok, thanks. I understand.

Comment: I edited to answer both questions.

Answer (score 2):

Merhaba Begüm!

To "make" an assessment means to examine something and judge it. It's the normal everyday use of the word.

To "do" an assessment means to follow an official procedure for assessments in a particular environment. I'm an English teacher (including 4 years in Turkey!), and every month I have to fill out student assessment forms. In my school environment, this process is "doing assessments". It's a task.

So to answer your question, "do compliance assessments" is correct.

İnşallah that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

They have slightly different meanings in that "make an assessment" implies a more formalized process.  But the distinction is relatively vague.

Comment: **Make** a _thing_. **Do** an _action_ . But an assessment can be either, right?